# asp.net core Identity user customization

Tags: asp.net-core-identity

## Detail

I am developing web application in asp.net core with Identity. now in my application I have two kind of user. Customer and Partner both have different profile information and login scenario.customer can login from simple signup from web page but partner can signup from different view with different mandatory fields.

## Problem

- How can I design Schema.
- what are the good practices in this case.
- What are the drawback.

## Code

This is  what I have done so far

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public CustomerProfile CustomerProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inheritance:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {}

public class Customer : ApplicationUser
{
    // Customer-specific properties
}

public class Partner : ApplicationUser
{
    // Partner-specific properties
}
```

By default, this will be implemented via STI (single-table inheritance). That means you'll have just your standard AspNetUsers table containing columns for the properties on `ApplicationUser` and all derived types. A discriminator column will be added to indicate which type was actually saved, which will then be used to instantiate the right type when queried.

For the most part, this works just fine. The one downside is that properties on derived classes *must* be nullable. The reason is simple: it would be impossible to provide values for `Customer` columns while saving a `Partner` and vice versa. However, the properties only need be nullable at the database-level. You can still require that they be set in forms and such via a view model.

The alternative is to use TPT (table-per-type). With this approach, you'll get AspNetUsers, but also Customers and Partners tables as well. However, the tables for the derived types will have columns corresponding only to the properties specific to that type and a foreign key back to AspNetUsers. All common properties are stored there. With this, you can now enforce columns have values at the database-level, but querying users will require a join. To use TPT, you simply add the `Table` attribute to your class, i.e. `[Table("Customers")]` and `[Table("Partners")]`, respectively.

The one important thing to keep in mind with using inheritance, though, is that you need to work with the type you actually want to be persisted. If you save an `ApplicationUser` instance, it will be an `ApplicationUser`, not a `Customer` or `Partner`. In this regard, you need to be careful with using the correct types with things like `UserManager` which generically reference the user type. Even if you create an instance of `Customer`, if you save it via an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`, it will upcast to `ApplicationUser` and *that* is what will be persisted. To create a new `Customer`, you'll need an instance of `UserManager<Customer>`. Likewise, for partners.

However, this also works to your benefit, as if you attempt to look up a user from an instance of `UserManager<Customer>` for example, you will only find them if they are in fact a `Customer`. In this way, it makes it trivially simple to have separate portals where only one or the other can log in, as you've indicated that you want.